# Meaning of +number in Java exception log

Tags: java

In these exception log lines:

```
Exception: java/lang/NullPointerException
at as.<init>(+95)
at fw.c(+8)
at bl.a(+27)
at bl.a(+116)
at gk.a(+110)
at bz.n(+28)
at bz.commandAction(+755)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable.callKeyPressed(Displayable.java:1161)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.callKeyPressed(Canvas.java:1070)
```

what is the meaning of `(+95)`, `(+8)`, `(+755)` ...etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are offsets of the instruction from where the exception propagated (thrown within each class). The code looks obfuscated BTW.

Comment: thanks! Btw, what does the `<init>` mean? Is it the construction of an `as` object?

Comment: Yes, it signifies the object's constructor. There is no method name to display so `<init>` is used instead.